# API CSV Import -> for ActivityContact -> invalid value for record_type_id

Tags: import, activities

Using API CSV import to try add entries to the civicrm_activity_contact table -> running out of ideas as to what I need to use for record_type_id (see screenshot) - any other ideas are welcome! Trying to get a GUI solution for a client.

[image]

Comment: API explorer says "Activity Assignees"?

Comment: Thanks D -> That's it! And it must be upper case -> 'activity assignees' does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API explorer says "Activity Assignees". And as noted in comment it must have the upper case A's.